# binding instead of connecting to IP

Tags: python

I have this python code that works only when the TCP_IP is localhost. If I change it to some other server IP for e.g. 23.21.167.61 then it fails to send the file even if the other server is listening.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print " New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    def run(self):
        filename='mytext.txt'
        f = open(filename,'rb')
        while True:
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            while (l):
                self.sock.send(l)
                #print('Sent ',repr(l))
                l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not l:
                f.close()
                self.sock.close()
                break

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print "Waiting for incoming connections..."
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print 'Got connection from ', (ip,port)
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I get an error while binding to IP. I can use connect method but then I will not be able to take advantage of threading as explained here...
http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client_file_transfer.php

```
[root@ip-10-93-136-166 ec2-user]# python server2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server2.py", line 34, in <module>
    tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: It looks like you're binding your side of a socket to an external address. That won't work. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need to copy files from many servers to central server.  I guess this can be achieved using threading as shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked when I used an empty string like '' instead of localhost

```
TCP_IP = ''
```

Then from client I connected and received file from remote server 23.21.167.61 
I am not sure what does empty string mean. But it solved the problem.